# Can't start monero daemon under Ubuntu WSL "Attempt to get hash from 0 height failed"

Tags: monerod, synchronization, windows, ubuntu

I am using monero v15.0.2 gui version under windows 10 Ubuntu WSL. I am getting this error when starting up. It doesn't seem to be downloading the blockchain at all. How can this be resolved?

[image]

Comment: Is this WSL1 or WSL2?

Comment: Did you build or using release download?

Comment: release download. its WSL2 @selsta

Comment: I would recommend to use the Windows version. See https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/534 and https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4139